# How to convert Result set into Json in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

`select id,name,age from person where id=1;`

This query gives result like below

```
id | name | age
1  |manoj | 20
```

I want a JSON like below

`"{"id":1,"name":"manoj","age":5}"`

I want a dynamic way.When I try another query from another table ,that result as like previous JSON

I want to generate JSON from a table and store into a column in MYSQL, I don't want to use php or other server side language for generate this JSON.

How can I get JSON in MYSQL ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `JSON_OBJECT()` function:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('id', id, 'name', name, 'age', age)
FROM person
WHERE id = 1;
```

This requires at least MySQL 5.7 or MariaDB 10.2.3, that's when all the JSON-related functions were added.

If you don't want to hard-code the column names into the query, you'll need to write a stored procedure that creates dynamic SQL, using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to get all the column names.

Comment: how to use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`? can you give a proper example..

Comment: Search for "MySQL dynamic sql" and you should find examples.

Comment: Throwing a function not found error on MariaDB 10.1.35

Comment: @peter The JSON functions require 10.2.3 or higher

Answer (score 0):

Look into JSON data type and JSON functions. If column is of JSON data type and insert string is in JSON format it's easy to insert and retrieve too.

[MySQL JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-converting-between-types)

[JSON functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-functions.html)