# Trying to use JSON_OBJECT function on mySQL database on Amazon AWS

Tags: php, mysql, json, amazon-web-services, pdo

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45160092/how-to-convert-result-set-into-json-in-mysql) on converting result sets to JSON

I am interested in using this function (which is why I was searching and found this post in the first place) but when I tried it, no results came back.

The answer on the page provided states that there is a minimum mySQL version number (5.7) you need to use this function.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way from the RDS screen (or some other way) to find the MySQL version number I set my database up with?
2. Assuming that the version is compliant, does my PHP PDO query work exactly the same way? If not, is there another way to do this with or without PHP PDO?

Comment: Failing that, just fetch the rows as normal and PHP `json_encode()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can verify your MySQL server version with this query:

```
SELECT VERSION();
```

If you use JSON_OBJECT(), the result will be returned to PDO as a string which happens to contain JSON-formatted results.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT JSON_OBJECT('id', id, 'name', name, 'age', age) as doc FROM person");
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($results);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["doc"]=>
    string(37) "{"id": 1, "age": 14, "name": "Harry"}"
  }
}
```

If MySQL doesn't support JSON_OBJECT(), you can fetch a regular result set as an associative array, and then use a PHP function like json_encode() to convert that array to JSON.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, name, age FROM person");
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$doc = json_encode($results);
echo $doc . "\n";
```

Output:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Harry","age":"14"}]
```